# What is IPC$ share detected by Samba?

Tags: 16.04, samba

I though I don't share anything, but samba reports some IPC$ share.

```
sudo smbstatus --shares

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------
IPC$         6029     myx        Mon Aug 29 13:56:37 2016
```

The only thing I installed in the last 15 days is Laravel + LAMP to locally run Laravel website.

Can I disable this share? And how I can see what does it actually share (dir, files,...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a Windows share, allowing null operations. [IPC$ share and null session behavior in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3034016):

> The IPC$ share is also known as a null session connection. By using
> this session, Windows lets anonymous users perform certain activities,
> such as enumerating the names of domain accounts and network shares.
>
> The IPC$ share is created by the Windows Server service. This special
> share exists to allow for subsequent named pipe connections to the
> server. The server's named pipes are created by built-in operating
> system components and by any applications or services that are
> installed on the system. When the named pipe is being created, the
> process specifies the security that is associated with the pipe, and
> then makes sure that access is only granted to the specified users or
> groups.

Comment: I searched for "ubuntu what is ipc" and found nothing LOL

Comment: But the real question is why the hell do I have it? I am having Ubuntu only on my machine. In my office there are Windows machines indeed.

Comment: Yet Googling "IPC$ samba" gives:  https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/securing-samba.html

I cite `The [IPC$] share is used for browsing purposes as well as to establish TCP/IP connections. `.  Furthermore, since Samba originates from the Windows world, you know that the terminology comes from Windows and hence you can look on Windows fora, or Microsoft Knowledge bases.  (Which is what I did)

Comment: No.  I think you totally misunderstand what Samba actually is.  Samba is a Unix reimplementation of the Windows file sharing protocol. (Server Message Block, SMB renamed Samba).  You are effectively emulating a Windows server when you run Samba.  Thus, you must also emulate IPC$, because IPC$ is used to anonymously connect to the machine offering Samba services, for several reasons.  One being, creating the list of available computers that share files.  Not having IPC$ would mean, your Linux machine emulating Windows File Shares wouldn't show up when you browse the (Windows) network.

Comment: And now a quick google search brings me here!

Comment: Add to the comment above.  A quick Google search comes here - you may want to include a quotation to make this a more solid answer in case the link you provide disappears.